# How to track Changes made in data tables between two access database files

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm fetching data from Microsoft access database file into PostgreSQL Database, then later some changes are added into Microsoft access database file and then re-uploaded into PostgreSQL Database as the latest dataset file with changes, now the challenge is how can I compare from previous state and then, if there is change how can I track these changes made between the previous data and the current data re-uploaded into PostgreSQL using spring boot as a back-end technology.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated